# Getter using property decorator returns object has no attribute

Tags: python

Code below returns `AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'r'`. I've re-read it multiple times though can't see what I'm missing. Can you?

```py
class Circle():

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, radius):

        # Control argument, raise an error(message) if <= 0
        if radius <= 0:
            raise ValueError('Invalid argument')

        # private instance variable
        self.__r = radius

        # Getter
        @property
        def r(self):
            return self.__r

        # Setter
        @r.setter
        def r(self, radius):
            if radius >= 0:
                self.__r = radius
            else:
                raise ValueError('Radius must be larger than 0')


c = Circle(5)
print(c.r) # >> AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'r'
```

Comment: You need to dedent the `@property` to the same level as `def __init__`, not *inside* `__init__`. Otherwise they're just local definitions inside `__init__` that aren't attached to anything, and disappear when `__init__` finishes.

Comment: `# private instance variable` **double-underscore name-mangling is not the same thing as private and shouldn't be thought of that way**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Eh. [Python's own docs call them "private"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private). It's not a *security* feature like some people think it is, but calling it private isn't *wrong*. It's not like "private" variables in most (any?) other language are really a security feature; in low-level languages you can just directly read the memory, in high-level languages you can typically use the reflection capabilities to access them. Python just removes the pretense of security, but the "security" is no worse than those other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property indentation is wrong, as it is currently defined inside the **init**.

```
class Circle:

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, radius):

        # Control argument, raise an error(message) if <= 0
        if radius <= 0:
            raise ValueError('Invalid argument')

        # private instance variable
        self.__r = radius

    # Getter
    @property
    def r(self):
        return self.__r

    # Setter
    @r.setter
    def r(self, radius):
        if radius >= 0:
            self.__r = radius
        else:
            raise ValueError('Radius must be larger than 0')
```